# How to use spread operator in setstate react class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am developing a component where I will get the data from a call back function. Initially the state of the component will be empty [], later once the callback function is called I need to update the values into the state. At a time I'll recive only one array, meaning user can add one item at a time that item will consists of nested objects and array values. I have added the logic for the same to handle the scenario, but when I am testing in jest when I am trying to add another set of item from mock meaning the user can select next item when the done with selecting and submitting the first item at that time my logic is getting failed, I am not getting where I went wrong, could any one help me to resolve this issue, thanks in advance! I have added the mock data structure and logic and jest test below.

```
Mock:

const items = {
   itemList: {
      itemOne: [{
         id: "01",
         category: "It-A",
         isCreated:"true"
}],
   itemDesc:[{
       id:"01",
       type:"A-1",
       isCreated:"true"
}]
}
ItemID:'123'
}


Code:
class ItemComp extends React.Component{
 this.state = {
   processingItems:[]

onAddItemHandle = (processingItem) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    processingItems: [...prevState.processingItems, processingItem]
}))
}


JEST:
describe('handleonAddItem', () => {
  it('should allow to add multiple items based on prevState', () => {
   
   const compView = mountWithIntl(
     <compView
       itemId={12}
     />
}
const instance = compView.find(compViewComponent).instance();
instance.onAddItemHandle(items) // when I am giving only one instance my logic is working
instance.onAddItemHandle(items) //when I am giving it for second time it's failing I am getting error like expected - 0 , received +18 I want to update the items here when user clicks for second time but it is failing. 
expect(instance.state.processingItems).toEqual([items])
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a ',' before the ItemID is the only issue I faced while reproducing.- https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-chaplygin-0ot56e?file=/src/App.js

```
const items = {
   itemList: { 
      itemOne: [{
         id: "01",
         category: "It-A",
         isCreated:"true"
}],
   itemDesc:[{
       id:"01",
       type:"A-1",
       isCreated:"true"
}]
},
ItemID:'123'
}
```